# Upgrading to Swfit 3: cannot override 'init' which has been marked unavailable

Tags: ios, swift, initialization

I just inherited an iOS project which incorporates [Apple's ResearchKit](https://github.com/ResearchKit/ResearchKit) (RK).

I have upgraded to the most recent version of RK and also to Swift 3.  While I have worked in iOS and RK, I am still not very confident.  Anyways, There is a class called `SurveyTask` which implements an `ORKOrderedTask` from RK.

[image]

> cannot override 'init' which has been marked unavailable

at the end this function, `stepz` already defined, we have:

```
super.init(identifier: "survey", steps: stepz)
```

I checked the `ORKOrderedTask` class definition, which has an `init` function.

[image]

I have been reading about [initializers](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html) but haven't found anything.  Using `override` or `convenience` before the `init` in `SurveyTask` doesn't change anything.  Same error.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

XCode version 8.1.

Comment: The init of the `ORKOrderedTask` seems to need an identifier so why don't u try to use the normal  'init(identifier:String, steps: [QRKStep]?)`

Comment: The thing is I don't think the purpose of the `init()` is to overwrite the other.  It is just to be run when `SurveyTask` is instantiated.  The call with `super` provides those arguments.

Comment: Try mark init as `open`, not `public`

Comment: @NikitaPatskov You mean changing the code inside the `ORKOrderedTask` definition?  That would be changing the ResearchKit code?

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind Can you please clarify what you are trying to achieve with `init`? There's no mention of it in the documentation, it's advised to use `initWithIdentifier` instead. https://github.com/ResearchKit/ResearchKit#3-create-a-task

Comment: @РоманПарадеев All the code in this function prepares the contents of the survey.  Each question in the survey is called a step, and the steps are appended to the array `stepz`.  This  `stepz` variable is then used as an argument calling `init()` of the extended `ORKOrderedTask`, the other argument is the identifier string. `super.init(identifier: "survey", steps: stepz)` is the last line of the `init()` function.

Answer (score 14):

Here's how you can mimic a parameterless initializer and avoid the `unavailable` error:

```swift
class MyClass: ParentWithUnavailableInitializer {
    init(workaround _: Void = ()) {
        // Call a designated initializer
        super.init(param: "a very sensible value")
    }
}

// At a call site
let obj = MyClass()
```

Works in Swift 3.2 and Swift 4.

Comment: Override ObjC selector to avoid odd `withWorkaround` interop:
`@objc(initObject) init(workaround _: Void = ()) { ... }`

Comment: @PhilippOtto Instead of overriding an unavailable initializer you create a new unrelated one. It looks parameterless at a call site, but in fact it's not.

Comment: Thanks @deej. What surprises me more is that a colleague of mine used this solution for CBPeripheral and he didnt even have to call the designated initializer of the superclass. That was when I learned that the init of the superclass is automatically called if there is only one designated init without parameters. So with the new "empty" initializer in the subclass the normally unavailable superclass init was called. Fascinating but unexpected

Comment: Can't be called manually but is called automatically? Sounds like a bug to me